# How to configure Cordova CLI to use custom project template repo for given platform?

Tags: ios, cordova, command-line-interface, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Cordova CLI is simple:

`cordova platform add ios`

Plus you can append `@<VERSION_TAG>` and so use a different version. But my goal is to have something like this:

`cordova platform add ios@https://github.com/<MY_FORK>/cordova-ios.git@<MY_VERSION_TAG/BRANCH>`

So `platform add` command will use my fork instead of https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git. Cordova CLI doesn't seem to allow this type of weird statement, but is there (where?) a way to customise it somehow to use a different repo URL for the Cordova platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it,

I found it while traversing Cordova-CLI files and then Cordova-Lib. Here's the answer:

`cordova platform add git-url#custom-branch`

And here is the source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js